# Data Undefined: useQuery Hook in React for GraphQL @apollo/client with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I have been trying to diagnose this issue for quite a while and can't determine why.

Using the useQuery hook as you can see. Get three variables out of it: loading, error, and data

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const myComponent = () => {
  
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS_BY_ID, {
    variables: { ids: store.get("ids") },
  });

 console.log(data);
 console.log(data.nodes);

  if (loading)return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

  return (
    <Fragment>
     
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

[The result of console.log(data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQBpZ.png)

Seems simple? I get an object with the property of nodes. Nodes looks like it equates to an array of objects.

Ok lets try console.log(data.nodes), should get and array of objects back...but only works like 1 out 50 times. Aka the one time is worked was when Next.js hot reloaded. When refreshed it never works. Majority of the time I get this error? Why is the property of 'nodes' undefined? I don't get why
[console.log(data.nodes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfJZH.png)

All I want to do is map through the array of object (data.nodes) and destructure out the variables...Am I overlooking something simple?

Comment: move logging after conditions

Comment: This is a known issue effecting various libraries specifically around fast refresh during development: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/13268#issuecomment-653583433

Comment: just follow apollo docs ... there is no (never) `data` props access before conditions ... `data` **can be undefined** until data loads, conditions are there to prevent this kind of errors ... google for 'useQuery undefined'

Comment: @xadm - can’t believe I overlooked that simple fact, didn’t try it yet, but will do. Odd how it worked once though…

Comment: @xadm I actually know why it worked that one time, it was because hot reloading, the data has already been loaded. When I added my console logs.